# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.getCharset()Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

My junit fails with exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.http.MediaType.getCharset()Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;

There are two more post with same issue but the solution provided dn't help me.

I have update my spring-core to 4.3.8.Release.

Exception occurs while executing the below code.

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/domains")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestJson)).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

It would be a great help if any one could share their ideas. Thank you !!

Answer (score 6):

I fixed by adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure that you use the same version of spring-web and spring-core.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with spring jar conflicts. Issue resolved by matching all the spring jar's to the same version.